# Variable frame rate playback

Tags: video

I have a variable frame rate h264 stream.I am streaming that using webrtc.
Any idea how the chrome browser would render the video ?.Rtp timestamps are
system generated and are no where related to capture time-instant ?
Also how does jitter buffer behave in case of variable frame rate ?

We are getting variable frame rate raw video and streaming it via webrtc to browser.